# PHP Template editor using file storage , database or both?

Tags: php, performance

i'm really confused i want to create a browser based template editor for my php template engine. so the use can update the code from the controller panel **(something like the wordpress appearance->editor)**

the question is what should i use a file storage and get the template list by using [glob](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) and update the file using file_put_content and get it using file_get_contents.

or save the template names and a description for the templates in the database and store the templates in a files

or store them all in a database

i'm really confused could someone give me a good answer please (but put performance in mind i used the default php template engine because of perfromance).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go with flat files, you'll be able to easily leverage opcode caches like APC with on the generated templates.  However, you'll also have to implement a semaphore to handle simultaneous attempts to write to the files.

Conversely with the database approach, you get mutual exclusion logic for free, but would have to write something else to create flat files in production, based on the db content, to get them APC cached.

Comment: i need the difference in the performance using database is easier but which of them is faster actually i can't depend on APC because my project is an open source and people my don't have APC installed

Comment: If you don't see leveraging APC as a requirement then I see no argument for using files.  If you did have support for exporting to files that could get OPCODE cached, that would make the template run faster in production.  When pulling from the db with eval(), the templates won't be OPCODE cacheable.

Comment: One more thought...  If the database is expected to be on another physical machine over the network, now you're looking at substantial overhead compared to a reference sitting right there on the Webserver, be it on disk or in memory.

Comment: well i won't use eval am thinking of using header function and set the content type php  this will make it cacheable or not ?

Comment: Hmm, well I thought your intention was to do some type of variable substitution with these templates.  Aren't they storing php code?  If they are you'll have to call some variation of `eval` _before_ echoing out any of the data.  Unless I'm missing something.  But to answer your direct question no.  I don't think the code is OPCODE cachable unless it's in a file.  OPCODE cache aside, like I was saying a second ago, a file by itself on the Webserver, is definitely going to be loaded faster than a query to a database first to get the template, no network I/O, local or otherwise.